# Creation of Always on Availability Group for BizTalk 2016 environment using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (14.0.17224.0)

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm following a step-by-step guide written by a Microsoft field engineer on below documentation to create BizTalk 2016 AOAG with SQL 2016 enterprise edition in conjunction with Server Management Studio (14.0.17224.0):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/high-availability-using-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups?redirectedfrom=MSDN

My question on preparing the availability group using Server Management Studio (14.0.17224.0) supports database DTC option is that new functionally added to SQL management studio (14.0.17224.0) and during creation of his lab environment he mention DTC support cannot be applied from the SSMS and must be done in script?

I created AG though SSMS GUI and ran query to  find DTC status on DATABASE as below

[image] :

--===Checking where there DTC support is ENABLED or NOT for BIZTALK 2016 SSODB======

`SELECT NAME,DTC_SUPPORT FROM sys.availability_groups`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Availability Groups is better H/A solution in my opinion. It comes with database-redundancy and a much faster failover which a BizTalk environmient will benifit from.

From SQL 2016 SP2 and SQL Server 2017 it also supports Cross Database Transaction inside instances in AOAG so you only need one instance (instead of 4 instance in SQL 2016 SP1).

I belive that a Windows Failover Cluster is more complex because you have a lot more shared resources while in Availiability Groups it is only the listner that is a resource in WFC.

Starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Service Pack 2 you can alter an availability group for distributed transactions. For SQL Server 2016 (13.x) versions before Service Pack 2, you need to drop, and recreate the availability group with the DTC_SUPPORT = PER_DB setting.

Answer (score 2):

**HOLD ON!**

The first thing you should do is really, double, triple check you really, absolutely 110% need (as in no other option) to use AOAG with BizTalk Server.

While supported, AOAG is in practice a **net negative with BizTalk Server** over regular failover clustering alone since it adds *significant additional complexity* to the setup, while providing *no incremental benefit* to BizTalk Server.

Note, this situation is specific to BizTalk Server.  Many apps can and do benefit from AOAG, just not BizTalk Server.

Comment: 100% agree and it’s more complex step need to be follow to setup BT2016 environment. So, can we use BT 2016 in traditional way like BizTalk 2013 R2 (I know we can use traditional way of failover clusters without AOAG setup) but need to have up and down side how that’s effect BizTalk environment?

Comment: BizTalk High Availability is exactly the same with 2016 as it was with all previous versions.  Two Clustered SQL Instances in a cross-failover setup is still the best config for BizTalk HA with the MSS in the same Resource Group as the SSODB.

Comment: If this is the case, why was support for it added to the product? What benefit does that give?

Comment: @TomW AOAG eliminated the need for cluster compatible storage, it was also the shiny new thing for a while.  The thing is, at this point, neither is often the right choice because practically everything is going up on VM's now.